# firestore rules tests always ends with timeout error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I am trying to test firestore security rules that I have wrote, but every time I am trying to run my tests I am getting timeout error.

Before I run tests, I start my firestore emulators with such command:

```
❯ npm run firebase:run:emulator

> warzywniax@0.0.0 firebase:run:emulator
> cd firebase && firebase emulators:start --project=warzywniax --import=./seed --export-on-exit

i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, firestore, storage
i  firestore: Importing data from /firebase/seed/firestore_export/firestore_export.overall_export_metadata
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
i  auth: Importing config from /firebase/seed/auth_export/config.json
i  auth: Importing accounts from /firebase/seed/auth_export/accounts.json
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ 127.0.0.1:9099 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ 127.0.0.1:9199 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150
```

It looks like everything is okay. My firestore emulator is hosted under ***127.0.0.1:8080*** and there is no any problem accessing this emulator via my web-browser.

Before I run any test, I am running some setup script on `setupFilesAfterEnv` jest hook. The whole setup script looks like this:

```js
import { initializeTestEnvironment, RulesTestEnvironment } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/';

export let testEnvironment: RulesTestEnvironment;
export let guestUserContext: firebase.firestore.Firestore;
beforeAll(async () => {
  testEnvironment = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    firestore: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8080,
    },
    projectId: 'warzywniax',
  });
  guestUserContext = testEnvironment.unauthenticatedContext().firestore();
  console.info('TEST_ENV is ready:\n', testEnvironment);
  console.info('GUEST_USER is ready:\n', guestUserContext);
});
```

Then if attempt to run some simple test like this one:

```js
import { assertSucceeds } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import { guestUserContext } from '../integration-setup';

describe('Offers collection tests', () => {
  it('should allow to read offers for any user', async () => {
    const testQuery = guestUserContext.collection('offers');

    expect(await assertSucceeds(testQuery.get()));
  });
});
```

it results with this error:

```
 FAIL  test/integration/firebase/firestore.rules.spec.ts (5.234 s)
  Offers collection tests
    ✕ should allow to read offers for any user (5001 ms)

  ● Offers collection tests › should allow to read offers for any user

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout.
```

I have checked was there any problem getting collection, but if I log `testQuery` it looks alright.

I have also followed advice from error above error, and I extended the timeout to 30s (`--testTimeout=30000`). What gives strange result. My test passed by I got such error anyway:

```
  console.error
    [2023-03-30T15:45:44.552Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

      at Logger.defaultLogHandler [as _logHandler] (node_modules/@firebase/logger/src/logger.ts:115:57)
      at Logger.Object.<anonymous>.Logger.error (node_modules/@firebase/logger/src/logger.ts:210:5)
      at x (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:124:11)
      at Pu.au (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:13778:20)
      at nc.op (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:13748:14)
      at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:14307:14
      at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:17414:73
      at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:17447:54

 PASS  test/integration/firebase/firestore.rules.spec.ts (10.335 s)
  Offers collection tests
    ✓ should allow to read offers for any user (10168 ms)
```

What, in my opinion, should make this test fall. Do you have any ideas what can be wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: expect requires a follow-up call to assert the value in the brackets: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectvalue

Comment: @Chris I add this `toBeDefined()` and it is not the case. I think the problem is somewhere in the connection configuration with testEnvFirestore, but I do not know where

Comment: Are you using `localhost` in any configurations or only `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue. I have several Jest tests related to Firestore rules, all of them failing due to Timeout while all my Firebase Database rules tests were passing.

What I learned after a lot of research was that, at least on my side, the problem was related to the test environment using `jsdom`. When I switched to the Jest default test environment, which is `node`, the tests start passing again.

The main help I found was this thread on (sic) React native repo.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36342

And the most important paragraph from the whole thread is this:
"The root issue here is that RN's Jest environment now only exports react-native as an export condition (not node), which means packages which export a node target might now resolve differently. In the case of firebase, it defaults back to ESM. This should've been labelled as a breaking change to the Jest setup to be honest - sorry about that."

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your setup and was able to get a passing test. Check the version numbers here to see if it is the cause of any issues. Also the outputs may be different in a meaningful way:

```js
import { initializeTestEnvironment } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';

export let testEnvironment;
export let guestUserContext;
beforeEach(async () => {
  testEnvironment = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    firestore: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8080,
    },
    projectId: 'warzywniax',
  });
  guestUserContext = testEnvironment.unauthenticatedContext().firestore();
  console.info('TEST_ENV is ready:\n', testEnvironment);
  console.info('GUEST_USER is ready:\n', guestUserContext);
});
```

```js
import { initializeTestEnvironment, assertSucceeds } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import { guestUserContext } from './lib.js';

describe('Offers collection tests', () => {
  it('should allow to read offers for any user', async () => {
    const testQuery = guestUserContext.collection('offers');

    await assertSucceeds(testQuery.get());
  });
});
```

node.js package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "rulestestingso",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing this",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "chris",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^2.0.7",
    "firebase": "^9.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0"
  }
}
```

```
$ mocha main.js


  Offers collection tests
TEST_ENV is ready:
 RulesTestEnvironmentImpl {
  projectId: 'warzywniax',
  emulators: { firestore: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8080 } },
  contexts: Set(1) {
    RulesTestContextImpl {
      projectId: 'warzywniax',
      emulators: [Object],
      authToken: undefined,
      destroyed: false,
      envDestroyed: false,
      app: [FirebaseAppImpl]
    }
  },
  destroyed: false
}
GUEST_USER is ready:
 Firestore {
  _delegate: Firestore {
    _authCredentials: FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider {
      authProvider: [Provider],
      currentUser: [User],
      tokenCounter: 0,
      forceRefresh: false,
      auth: null
    },
    _appCheckCredentials: FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider {
      appCheckProvider: [Provider],
      forceRefresh: false,
      appCheck: null,
      latestAppCheckToken: null
    },
    _databaseId: DatabaseId { projectId: 'warzywniax', database: '(default)' },
    _app: FirebaseAppImpl {
      _isDeleted: false,
      _options: [Object],
      _config: [Object],
      _name: '_Firebase_RulesUnitTesting_1680224130695_0.0042143144476949335',
      _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
      _container: [ComponentContainer]
    },
    type: 'firestore',
    _persistenceKey: '_Firebase_RulesUnitTesting_1680224130695_0.0042143144476949335',
    _settings: FirestoreSettingsImpl {
      host: '127.0.0.1:8080',
      ssl: false,
      credentials: undefined,
      ignoreUndefinedProperties: false,
      cache: undefined,
      cacheSizeBytes: 41943040,
      experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
      experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: false,
      useFetchStreams: true
    },
    _settingsFrozen: false,
    _queue: AsyncQueueImpl {
      tail: [Promise],
      retryableOps: [],
      _isShuttingDown: false,
      delayedOperations: [],
      failure: null,
      operationInProgress: false,
      skipNonRestrictedTasks: false,
      timerIdsToSkip: [],
      backoff: [ExponentialBackoff],
      visibilityHandler: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  },
  _persistenceProvider: IndexedDbPersistenceProvider {},
  INTERNAL: { delete: [Function: delete] },
  _appCompat: FirebaseAppImpl {
    _delegate: FirebaseAppImpl {
      _isDeleted: false,
      _options: [Object],
      _config: [Object],
      _name: '_Firebase_RulesUnitTesting_1680224130695_0.0042143144476949335',
      _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
      _container: [ComponentContainer]
    },
    firebase: <ref *1> {
      __esModule: true,
      initializeApp: [Function: initializeAppCompat],
      app: [Function],
      registerVersion: [Function: registerVersion],
      setLogLevel: [Function: setLogLevel],
      onLog: [Function: onLog],
      apps: [Getter],
      SDK_VERSION: '9.19.0',
      INTERNAL: [Object],
      default: [Circular *1],
      database: [Function],
      firestore: [Function],
      storage: [Function]
    },
    container: ComponentContainer {
      name: '_Firebase_RulesUnitTesting_1680224130695_0.0042143144476949335',
      providers: [Map]
    }
  }
}
    ✔ should allow to read offers for any user (1049ms)


  1 passing (1s)
```

Comment: why you use mocha to run your tests `mocha main.js`

Comment: Honest answer: so I don't have to find imports for the test artifacts like `BeforeEach` and `describe` :D